# Why does this cause an infinite loop in C#?

Tags: c#

```cs
 var driver = "";

         while (driver != "y" || driver != "n" || driver != "Y" || driver != "N")
                { 
                   Console.WriteLine("Driver? (y/n)");
                   driver = Console.ReadLine();
                }
```

I can enter Y, y, N, n, or anything at all, and it just keeps asking...

Comment: you probably want to check if the input is **none** of the above, not if it is un-equal to `y` **or** `Y`.

Comment: Any time you check "a must be different from b or a must be different from c", it will **always** be true, because no matter what `a` is, it will always be different from either b or c. If it's equal to b, it will be different from c, and vice versa. Most likely you want to use "and", as in `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Just think it through... If you enter `"y"`, then `driver != "y"` is false, which is correct, but since `||` evaluates the right-hand side if the left-hand side is false, we then go on to check `driver != "n"`, and this is true. Any input you can enter gives the same result -- if it's equal to `"n"` then it's not equal to `"y"`  and so on. You probably wanted `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: learn about [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to check if the input is **none** of the above. In other words it must not be equal to the `'y'` **and** not equal to `'n'` and so on. However you check if it is not equal to `'y'` **or** not equal to `'n'` and so on. Having said this try this:

```
while (driver != "y" && driver != "n" && driver != "Y" && driver != "N")
```